# Python Zybooks lab function definition input

Tags: python

I have a zybooks lab with the prompt:
Write a function max_magnitude() with two integer input parameters that returns the largest magnitude value. Use the function in a program that takes two integer inputs, and outputs the largest magnitude value.

My code is:

```
def max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2):
   if abs(user_val1) > abs(user_val2):
      return user_val1
   else:
      return user_val2
user_val1 = int(input())
user_val2 = int(input())
print(max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2))
```

It works when the input is given as 2 integers, but when the input is something like "max_magnitude(5,8)" then it fails. How can I get the code to work with that form of input?

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3):
    return max([user_val1,user_val2,user_val3],key=abs)
def main():    
    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())
    user_val3 = int(input())
    print(max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2):
    if abs(int(user_val1)) > abs(int(user_val2)):
      return user_val1
    else:
      return user_val2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_val1 = input()
    user_val2 = input()
    print(max_magnitude(user_val1, user_val2))
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.